# Cannot import name 'socker'

Tags: python

Initial note: I know there are many of these type posts for python but I've tried many of the solutions and they have not worked for me.

File structure:

```
/nickdima
  __init__.py

  /test_pong
    __init__.py
    pong.py
```

**/nickdima/__init__.py:**

```
from flask_socketio import Socketio

socker = SocketIO()

from test_pong import pong

def create_app():

  app = Flask(__name__)

  socker.init_app(app)

  return app
```

**/nickdima/test_pong/pong.py**

```
from __main__ import socker

@socker.on('connect')
def handle_connect():
  print('connected')
```

When I run this code on Heroku I get the error:

```
from __main__ import socker
ImportError: cannot import name 'socker'
```

I'm fairly certain this is related to a circular import but I cannot solve it.

I've tried putting: `from test_pong import pong`
inside the `create_app()` function to "delay the import" locally but to no avail and I get the same error `cannot import name 'socker'`

Comment: You are looking for `socket` and not `socker`

Comment: @ChukwuemekaInya even if i have a consistent naming of 'socker' everywhere, does that matter?

Comment: I bet this is because you import from `__main__`. Do not do that, like ever. You have no control over what `__main__` is (it changes depending on the entry point). And that's most likely why it fails.

Comment: @freakish i tried doing import nickdima.test_pong.pong and that didn't work. I tried adding \__main__ based on this: https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/561 <-- scroll down a few comments to see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so after further inspection here's what I suggest:

```
/nickdima
  __init__.py
  socker.py
  /test_pong
    __init__.py
    pong.py
```

**/nickdima/socker.py**

```
from flask_socketio import Socketio
socker = SocketIO()
```

**/nickdima/__init__.py:**

```
from nickidima.socker import socker
from nickidima.test_pong import pong

def create_app():
  app = Flask(__name__)
  socker.init_app(app)
  return app
```

**/nickdima/test_pong/pong.py**

```
from nickidima.socker import socker

@socker.on('connect')
def handle_connect():
  print('connected')
```

This way you no longer have circular dependencies!

Imports are relative to the root directory where `nickidima` is placed. I'm not sure how Heroku works with this kind of importing (actually I've never used Heroku) but I hope you get the idea and will be able to tweak it to your needs.

The most important lesson: circular dependencies are almost always a sign of a bad design and almost always can be replaced with non-circular dependencies. And when they can: do it.

**Side note:** I'm following your naming convention (socker?) but seriously, you should fix it. :)

Comment: Thank you so much!! This works! Quick question I'm wondering if you can provide some clarity on for me? In most of the Flask / Flask-socketio apps i've seen, they instantiate all the extentions in the same file as the app factory (https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flack/blob/master/flack/__init__.py) as opposed to a separate file. Why did that not work in my case?

Comment: Also, note taken, I will rename my "socker" object to socketio haha

Comment: This is alright I guess, but it seems strange to import `pong` just for its side effects. I think wrapping that in a function is better. Consider [this instead](https://repl.it/repls/InformalOutgoingFlashmemory)

Comment: @NickDima the project you've linked uses circular dependencies (`__init__.py` imports `events` which imports `__init__.py`). This isn't a problem if you know exactly what you're doing and are *very* careful about what you import, when, and where, but it's definitely a code smell you should seek to eliminate if possible.

Comment: @AdamSmith Thank you for the clarification on the link I posted! I really like that pattern you showed in your repl link. I've been wondering how to best organize the large amount of sockets I eventually want to have on my app and that seems super convenient! Really appreciate the share!